# System.Data.DataRowView (shown in multicolumn combo box)

Tags: c#, windows, combobox

I trying to do multi column in combo box, and I wanted justify the second column,

but the Items shown in combo box replaced with after I done the following code: **System.Data.DataRowView**

```
string sql = "SELECT customer.customer, arcustmst.cust_name_1 FROM customer INNER JOIN arcustmst ON customer.customer=arcustmst.cust_code";

        SqlCommand custcom = new SqlCommand(sql, myconnection);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(custcom);
        DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
        da.Fill(ds, "customerFrom");

        cboFrom.DisplayMember = "customer.customer" + string.Format({0,-5}, "arcustmst.cust_name_1");
        cboFrom.ValueMember = "customer.customer" + string.Format({0,-5}, "arcustmst.cust_name_1");
        cboFrom.DataSource = ds.Tables["customerFrom"];
```

Result:

[image]
Can anyone please help and guide.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess the shift is due to the font not the code. You'd probably not get this in a mono-sized font.

Comment: @EmmadKareem How to say the shift is due to the font? Can you explain abit? Thanks

Comment: Monospaced fonts such as Courier have the same width for all charachters. So if you type 3 characters they will have the same width as any other 3 characters. If you use a non-Monospaced font, each character would have a different width.

Comment: @EmmadKareem Great! Thanks for the explanation and I did it. Apreciated your help